# Problems occurred when installing first laravel app

Tags: php, laravel

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/sail is locked to version v1.23.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - laravel/sail v1.23.0 requires php ^8.0 -> your php version (7.4; overridden via config.platform, actual: 7.3.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - league/flysystem 1.1.10 requires ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
    - laravel/framework v8.83.27 requires league/flysystem ^1.1 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.1.10].
    - laravel/framework is locked to version v8.83.27 and an update of this package was not requested.

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\AppServ\php7\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-fileinfo` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require symfony/twig-pack:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require symfony/twig-pack:^2.1" if you know which you need.
```

I am trying to create a new laravel app by running `composer global require laravel/installer` followed by `laravel new demo-app` then the above error occurred. I am trying to configure the version of PHP but I am not sure where to figure out the problems inside the app installation.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your system PHP is set to either version 7.4 or 7.3.10 and the installation need a php version of 8.0 or higher. Can i ask how you have your development environment setup?

Comment: The first time I run PHP programs is I using xampp/htdocs folder after I installed the xampp panel

Comment: May I ask how to upgrade my PHP to 8.0 or higher versions?

Comment: This should be in comment section, not posted as an answer. [Click](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

Answer (score 0):

- 1- Open this file `C:\AppServ\php7\php.ini` ( *you will find `php.ini` file in the same folder where `php.exe` exists* )
- 2- search for `fileinfo`
- 3- uncoment it :

change

```
;extension=fileinfo
```

to

```
extension=fileinfo
```

- 4- run

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your_application_name_goes_here
```